# App using latitude and longitude, should decimal degrees be separate a selection from metric?

Tags: coordinate-system, development, ux

I am coding a mobile app that displays coordinates in parts of the interface. We currently have an option to toggle between Imperial and Metric. But I am unsure if decimal degrees (vs D/M/S) should be its own option or if it is something that should be tied to the Imperial/Metric display option as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest choice -- from a logic point-of-view, not a graphical or aesthetic one -- for you, the designer:

- Imperial

  Metric

  Degrees-Minutes-Seconds

  Decimal Degrees

  Degrees-Decimal Minutes [you didn't mention this, but I propose it as an additional case]

A slightly more complex but perhaps a better approach -- because it can remember the user's *other*, "unused" preference -- is the two-tiered one:

- Projected

  - Imperial

    Metric

  Geographic

  - Degrees-Minutes-Seconds

    Decimal Degrees

    Degrees-Decimal Minutes

Whichever first-tier is *not* chosen would be greyed out (disabled) but would still show the second-tier choice for the case that it *was* enabled.